# React Native Jest Test Suite Fails: TypeError: Cannot read property 'propTypes' of undefined

Tags: react-native, jestjs

I am trying to use the Jest test suite that comes with the app created with react-native init but I am getting this error when I run npm test:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'propTypes' of undefined

  at propTypes (node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Animated/src/createAnimatedComponent.js:178:31)
  at Object.oldCreate [as createAnimatedComponent] (node_modules/react-native/jest/setup.js:79:23)
  at Object.Animated (node_modules/react-navigation-stack/lib/commonjs/views/BorderlessButton.tsx:5:28)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-navigation-stack/lib/commonjs/views/TouchableItem.tsx:19:1)
```

This is the code of the test that is failing...

```
import 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import App from '../App';

import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

beforeAll(() => { 
  jest.mock('@react-native-community/async-storage');
});

it('renders correctly', () => {
  renderer.create(<App />);
});
```

Not sure how to resolve it, several errors I was getting i managed to fix by either mocking the module (like AsyncStorage, geolocation, NetInfo) or adding their package name to the jest object in package.json like so:

```
 "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!(react-native|react-native-barcode-builder|react-native-maps|react-native-android-open-settings|react-native-qrcode-scanner|react-native-permissions|react-native-camera|react-native-google-maps-directions|jsbarcode|react-native-picker-select|react-native-datepicker|react-native-touch-id|react-native-screens|react-native-gesture-handler|react-navigation|react-navigation-stack)/)"
    ]
  }
```

My babel.config file just has...

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
};
```

Am I missing some step in the configuration? Not sure if it helps but I am using React Native v0.60.5. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the right mocks for `react-native-gesture-handler` fixed it for me. I had to add:

```
"setupFiles": [
      "./node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/jestSetup.js"
    ],
```

You can find more documentation here:
https://kmagiera.github.io/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/getting-started.html#testing

Answer (score 0):

You should define jest config like this in your package.json.

```
 "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "collectCoverage": true,
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
    "moduleDirectories": [
      "node_modules",
      "components"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.js$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-native/jest/preprocessor.js"
    },
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/jest/setup.js"
    ],
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!(jest-)?react-native)"
    ],
    "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/",
      "/jest",
      "assets",
      "lib"
    ],
    "modulePathIgnorePatterns": [
      "package",
      "assets",
      "lib"
    ]
  },
```